# Extremely slow socket data throughput on Android 11?

Tags: performance, sockets, android-11

I've seen some posts elsewhere about very slow file access after "upgrading" a device to Android 11.  I'm not having that, but I AM having unbelievably slow performance in a small app that uses sockets.  It's a client app that uses a socket to send a request to a server (mine) that monitors my solar installation, to get data back about how it has been performing etc.  So the socket interaction is in a separate thread from the UI, and uses runOnUIThread to call a function that updates the UI with the received data.  The request data is only a few bytes, maybe 20 or so maximum: the data coming back varies from a few hundred bytes to maybe 50000 bytes or thereabouts.

If I run this app on my phone (Android 8.1) it is fine - it takes 1.5 to 2 seconds to send the request, get the data back, and update the UI.  Perfectly fine.  It's the same on an older tablet running Android 7.1.2 too.  But I have just recently acquired a flash (read expensive) new Samsung tablet running Android 11, and its performance is woeful - the same app doing the same operation takes anything up to 30 seconds, or even more.  And it is exactly the same app, exactly the same code.  Both devices are running on the same network, so the only significant difference seems to be the Android version.  It is repeatable ad nauseum, so it isn't momentary network load either.  The app is built to target API level 26 - it has to be so it can run on all the devices it needs to.  It is not a commercial app, just something for my own use, but I am totally bewildered by this behaviour.

The other thing I have noted with this new tablet is that it is unable to provide a video stream from a surveillance IP camera I have at home.  I use the TinyCam Pro app from Google Play for this.  It can connect, but it has never yet managed to give me a picture, regardless of how good my connection is.  Again, my phone and the older tablet can do this more often than not, and the new tablet would have far more horsepower than either of them.  There is some sort of serious bottleneck in there!

Has anyone else seen this type of thing on Android 11?  If so, is there anything that can be done about it, that is usable on earlier versions too?  Or do we just have to wait for Android 11.1?

EDIT: I've done some more investigation on this, and I think I have now pinned it down to a 4G network bandwidth issue.  I said that the tablet and the phone were doing exactly the same thing, but I have since remembered that they do NOT use the same carrier for their mobile connections.  So it's not EXACTLY the same thing.  I would actually expect the network capacity for the tablet's carrier to be superior to that of the phone's carrier, but that appears not to be the case where I am at the moment.  So I think I have to take back my evil thoughts about the tablet, and maybe even Android 11.  Interesting how easy it is to be misled, and how hard it can be to genuinely compare apples with apples when there are so many variables and so many links in the chain.  I'll be doing some more tests and comparisons when back in the city, where network capacity should be much more alike for the two carriers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes its true. While compare to Android 11 and Android 8 there is a lot of changes updated because of security issue.

May be, If your managing some file in mobile storage mnt/sdcard/ here in this path its speed of access or managing a file in this path its restricted and its becomes less. So, if your using this path please change it like below because it will cause youe app to process slow.

solution - Try to use this file access path is Android/data/data/packageName/

I mean if your using this logic to access file - Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
instead of above try this - Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)

refer this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

I hopes it will help you...